# Fetching MySQL records: Warning: Illegal offset type

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I've been charged with updating a site to php7 as the hosting company is upgrading the server soon. I never wrote the original code and it's so dated i'm having an issue with the below code.

After updating `mysql_num_fields`, `mysql_fetch_array`, and `mysql_field_name` to the new `mysqli` functions I'm now getting the error

> Warning: Illegal offset type.

I've looked at the other answers for this but none match the code. I'm totally lost.

```
$fieldCount = mysqli_num_fields($result);
$k = 0;
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $fieldCount; $i++) {
        $fieldName = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i);
        $arrRecords[$k][$fieldName] = $record[$fieldName];
    }
    $k++;
}
```

Comment: `$arrRecords = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the below code will help you to get you desired output.

```
//$fieldCount = mysqli_num_fields($result);
$k = 0; 
$arrRecords = array();
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach ($record as $key=>$val) {
        $arrRecords[$k][$key] = $val;            
    }
    $k++;
} 
print_r($arrRecords);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to have solved the issue.